# How to express variable type in match arm?

Tags: rust, serde-json

I'm trying to parse a piece of json string using [`serde_json`](https://docs.serde.rs/serde_json/) in Rust. I want to match the result of the parse using the following syntax:

```
match serde_json::from_str(msg.to_text().unwrap()) {
    Ok(result) => {
        println!("Parsed: {}", response.text);
    }
    Err(error) => {
        println!("Failed to parse: {}", error);
    }
}
```

but the compiler complains to me that he doesn't know the type of the `result` and of course, he is right. But how can I tell him the type of the `result`? I tried the following code, but it didn't work either. So I want to express the type of variable in the match arm.

```
match serde_json::from_str(msg.to_text().unwrap()) {
    Ok(result: Response) => {
        println!("Parsed: {}", response.text);
    }
    Err(error) => {
        println!("Failed to parse: {}, {}", error, msg.to_text.unwrap());
    }
}
```

Comment: it's generally not needed in a real application.

Comment: @Stargateur What do you mean? Just using `unwrap`?

Comment: no the type infering would work without explicit hint

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a few way you can specify the type. Either you can explicitly specify it using [type parameters in the function call](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/generics/gen_fn.html), i.e. by using this syntax `func::<T>()`.

```rust
match serde_json::from_str::<Response>(json) {
    Ok(response) => {}
    Err(err) => {}
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can assign the initial result to a variable, and hint the type there, i.e.

```rust
let res: Result<Response, _> = serde_json::from_str(json);
match res {
    Ok(response) => {}
    Err(err) => {}
}
```

or

```rust
match serde_json::from_str(json) {
    Ok(response) => {
        let response: Response = response;
    }
    Err(err) => {}
}
```

---

Lastly you can also use [@ bindings](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-03-pattern-syntax.html#-bindings). However, this doesn't work if your type is an `enum`, as then you'd have to specify the exact variant you wanted.

As in, if `Response` was an `enum` you could have multiple `Ok(resp @ Response::???)` match arms. But you couldn't have a single `Ok(resp @ Response)` match arm.

```rust
match serde_json::from_str(json) {
    Ok(response @ Response { .. }) => {}
    Err(err) => {}
}
```